# sbt on Windows how to run a Scala file?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a Scala file in  "..sbt\src\main\scala.."

When I use the "run" command , I get an "access denied" error:

> run
>   [info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/<>/Desktop/Spark/spark_disk/sbt/}sbt...
>   [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
>   [error] (*:update) java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\<>\Desktop\Spark\spark_disk\sbt\ivy.sbt.ivy.lock (Access is denied)

I checked all the permissions and I seem to have "full control" access and running in Administrator mode also gave me the same error.  So I am not sure what this error refers to.

Comment: Have you searched for that error (on Google, Stack Overflow) and tried some of the suggestions from the Java world?

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by showing "Hidden items"  in the sbt/ivy directory  to view the sbt.ivy.lock file and then right-click on the file-> Properties-> uncheck the "Hidden" box  for its Attributes. Then I was able to use run without getting that error.

Comment: Cool! You should write that as an answer to your question and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by showing "Hidden items" in the sbt/ivy directory to view the sbt.ivy.lock file and then right-click on the file-> Properties-> uncheck the "Hidden" box for its Attributes. Then I was able to use run without getting that error.